# Error loading object in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm creating a viewer application in Angular following the basic application tutorial on the forge site (https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload).

Everything is ok, until I call the loadDocument() function. It throws the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Anyone has any idea of what's going on? I've tried with different objects and I've made sure the translation to svf format was completed.

Thanks for the help!

-- EDIT:
Here's the code for the app (`<urn>` and `<token>` were replaced with the correct values):

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

declare var Autodesk: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-autodesk-forge-viewer',
    templateUrl: './panel.autodesk.viewer.component.html'
})
export class PanelAutodeskViewerComponent
    implements  AfterViewInit,
                OnInit
{
    private viewer: any;
    options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        language: "en",
        accessToken: "<token>"
    }

    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

    ngOnInit() {

    }    

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(this.options, function onInitialized() {
            this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('ForgeViewer');
            this.viewer.registerViewer(this.viewer.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
            this.viewer.loadDocument('urn:<urn>', this.onDocumentLoadSuccess, this.onDocumentLoadFailure);
        });
    }

    private onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
        // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
        // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
        // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
        var viewables = this.viewer.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
        if (viewables.length === 0) {
            console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
            return;
        }

        // Choose any of the avialble viewables
        this.viewer.selectItem(viewables[0].data, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail);
    }

    private onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
    }

    private onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
        console.log('onItemLoadSuccess()!');
        console.log(viewer);
        console.log(item);

        // Congratulations! The viewer is now ready to be used.
        console.log('Viewers are equal: ' + (viewer === this.viewer.getCurrentViewer()));
    }

    private onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
        console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an error for the Autodesk analytics SDK, it's not related to load a model from the Forge. Could you do me a favor to post the full code or example code you used in your viewer app, please?

Comment: BTW, could you add this line `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.logger.setLevel( Autodesk.Viewing.Private.LogLevels.NONE );` to your callback function of the `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`? The error message should be gone.

Comment: @EasonKang Thanks, I edited the question with the code. I'll try adding that to the callback function.

Comment: @EasonKang I added that line of code and the error still appears.

Comment: Sorry, I have some wrong typing before. Please add this line `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.logger.setLevel( Autodesk.Viewing.Private.LogLevels.NONE ); `,  instead of `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.logger.setLevel( avp.LogLevels.NONE ); `. Your code is fine, and should work fine.

Comment: @EasonKang Tried with the new code line and I still get the same error. I know it's weird because I copied and pasted the code on the forge site, but somehow it shows that error and the viewer doesn't load, even though the code appears to work fine.

Comment: Could you provide the executing environment information of your app? For example, OS, browser, Forge Viewer version, Nodejs version, etc.

Comment: @EasonKang Of Course!
Windows 10 64 bits,
Mozilla Firefox 54.0.1 64 bits,
Node: 8.1.3,
Angular: 4.0,
Forge Viewer: v2,
Viewer3D.js and Three.js latest version,

Comment: @EasonKang If you need anything else please let me know

Comment: Is your three.js from here `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.min.js` or without the suffix of min?? Forge viewer is only compatible with it private owned version r71.

Comment: @EasonKang I used the files with min, https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.min.js and https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js

Comment: To make sure we are in the same boat, please test your model with the master branch of this sample from my colleague: `https://github.com/JohnOnSoftware/Forge.Viewer.Classroom.Trainning`.

In addition, please add `?v=2.14` suffix to library links of the Forge Viewer.

Comment: @EasonKang Ok, just did that. I'm getting the same error `XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload
Line Number 1, Column 1` multiple times. Also, it says that the model is empty, which is weird because I used the Elephant.obj that came with the C# Forge Example.

Comment: One more thing to be checked. Is your urn is in this format?? Like this urn from the Forge step-by-step tutorials: `dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXktYnVja2V0L215LWF3ZXNvbWUtZm9yZ2UtZmlsZS5ydnQ`

Comment: @EasonKang Yes, I have the urn in base64

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm checking with my colleagues and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: @EasonKang Thank you very much

Comment: Would you mind to do one more thing for me? Open this official demo site and click some icon to load a model to check if the error message is still there.

https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/

Comment: @EasonKang just tried 2 of those models and they work fine.

Comment: @EasonKang The XML error is there though

Comment: Ok, it seems that remote viewer app is working fine on your side. For testing, let's add two line after the `this.viewer.selectItem(viewables[0].data, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail);`, i.e. `var lmv = this.viewer.getCurrentViewer(); lmv.loadModel( this.viewer.urn, {}, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail );` in your app, and make some changes then add it into the `Forge.Viewer.Classroom.Tra‌​inning`.

Comment: @EasonKang Hi, sorry for the late relply. Just tried and still nothing, on my app viewer still doesn't load and the XML error is still there. On `Forge.Viewer.Classroom.Tra‌​inning`, the model still doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message `XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload Line Number 1, Column 1:` 
shouldn't cause the issue you addressed. Your model should be loaded and shown in the viewer without any problem.

If you can provide a reproducible case demonstrating that, I will gladly investigate what happened to your app. Those following items should be in the reproducible case:

1. A short exact description of what you are trying to achieve. The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
2. A complete yet minimal sample source model to run a test in.
3. A complete yet minimal Forge app that can be run and debugged with a simple procedure to analyze its behavior live in the sample model.
   Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g. which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

If your reproducible case could not be posted here publicly, please send it to the `forge.help@autodesk.com` and **remove sensitive data or information before you send.**

Comment: Ok, many thanks. Will try to fix it this week end and send you the project next week. Thanks again!